# What is the Windows analog of the Linux watch command?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line

I'm looking for a Windows program/script/command line function that works like Linux's `watch` program.

[`watch`](http://ss64.com/bash/watch.html) periodically calls another program/whatever and shows the result, which is great for refreshing an output file or similar every second:

```
watch cat my-output.txt
```

or, more powerfully:

```
watch grep "fail" my-output.txt
```

I've looked for it in cygwin's library, but it doesn't seem to be present.

Comment: Hey anon, `while (1) { cls;kubectl get nodes; sleep 5}` Thank me later.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`watch` is available in Cygwin, in the `procps-ng`⁰ package as listed [here](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/procps-ng.html) (this info can be found via the package search on the website, [here](http://cygwin.com/packages/)). I don't think this package is installed by the default cygwin setup, but it is one I usually select on new installs in order to have the watch command available.

The location of tools in packages typically match package names in Linux distributions (the package containing `watch` is procps on Debian and Ubuntu too) so if the Cygwin package search function fails you, info for/from Linux distributions may offer clues. In this example the exact naming is no longer the case, though searching for procps would find procps-ng.

--

<sup>[0] `procps` is now deprecated (as noted [here](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2012-April/022845.html) and [here](https://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/procps.html)), the original package stopped being maintained and a couple of distros forked it to apply pending patches. In some places it is still called `procps` but in others like cygwin the new name was used</sup>

Comment: How is this and answer?

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer – the question asked for something like `watch` under Windows. What is it about running `watch` in Windows (via the cygwin port) that you don't think is sufficiently like `watch` for Windows?

Answer (score 63):

Write your own. Let's say file `watch.bat` contains :

```
@ECHO OFF
:loop
  cls
  %*
  timeout /t 5 > NUL
goto loop
```

and call it via, for example:

```
watch echo test
```

will echo `test` every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Keilaron: Note that your edit was bad and I had to fix it.  Please be more careful.

Comment: Simple but great. Avoids installing cygwin just for that single command. Vielen Dank!

Comment: Great! This should be the accepted answer! ;)

Comment: Is there a way to make it accept the timeout parameter as an argument?

Comment: @Shayan yes, easily. Just use %1 for the first argument like this: `timeout /t %1 > nul`

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer but how do I call the bat file now? It used to be `watch echo test` now how do I call it?

Answer (score 52):

**Powershell has the `while` command. You can use it like in Linux:**

```
while (1) {your_command; sleep 5}
```

**Linux version:**

```
while true; do your_command; sleep5; done
```

**Others:**

```
while ($true) {netstat -an | findstr 23560; sleep 5; date}
```

Comment: You can just use `while (1)`, because `1` is truthy.

Comment: I also found that you can use "clear" as the last statement, so it behaves more like watch.

Comment: To better mimic `watch` you can also use `date -format s` as the first command to show the time.

Answer (score 20):

A generic Windows command oneliner to accomplish this:

```
for /l %g in () do @( echo test & timeout /t 2 )
```

Replace "echo test" with the command you wish to run repeatedly.

Comment: nice one, simple one liner that does the trick

Answer (score 9):

It's a PowerShell one liner:

```
while ($true) { <your command here> | Out-Host; Sleep 5; Clear }
```

Comment: I'd put `Clear` first.

Comment: it depends on how long your command takes to run and then output to display.... you can change the order, but this is the general idea

Answer (score 8):

This is how I would do it in PowerShell:

```
while(1){ netstat -an|grep 1920;start-sleep -seconds 2;clear }
```

The condition `while(1)` is equivalent to `while true`, looping indefinitely.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote this little PowerShell module to do what you were looking for.  Just put it in

```
C:\Users\[username]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Watch
```

and run `import-module watch` in PowerShell.

---

```
# ---- BEGIN SCRIPT
# Author:       John Rizzo
# Created:      06/12/2014
# Last Updated: 06/12/2014
# Website:      http://www.johnrizzo.net

function Watch {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True,ConfirmImpact='High')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [int]$interval = 10,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$command
    )
    process {
        $cmd = [scriptblock]::Create($command);
        While($True) {
            cls;
            Write-Host "Command: " $command;
            $cmd.Invoke();
            sleep $interval;
        }
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -function Watch

# --- END SCRIPT
```

Comment: Looks pretty good but I would encourage the function to be in the Verb-Noun format (e.g. ```Watch-Command```) with an alias of ```Watch``` (```Set-Alias -Name Watch -item Watch-Command```).

Comment: Thanks! See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1598420/1235719) for some improvements I added

Answer (score 3):

You can also make up a delay using the PING command, for example:

```
@echo off
:loop
  cls
  dir c:\temp
  REM 5000mS (5 sec) delay...
  ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL
goto loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when needing to check the file size of a file actively being worked on by another process. I ended up cloning the functionality of watch on Windows. The compiled exe as well as the source is available at the site.

[watch for Windows](http://www.garrettgalloway.com/index.php?p=projects&e=7)

Answer (score 2):

I created a watch command for windows called llwatch.

The code is both on my website [landenlabs.com](http://landenlabs.com/)

and also on [GitHub](https://github.com/landenlabs/llwatch)

You may need to use x64 to watch x64 programs and x32 for the others. 
Not sure how picky windows is.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... Welcome to [su]!

Answer (score 1):

what @harrymc said except with sleep
watch.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
:loop
  %*
  sleep 5
goto loop
```

./watch.bat npm run test

`npm run test` every 5 sec

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command in windows **cmd** (not working in powershell):

```
for /l %g in () do @( <your-command> & timeout /t 1 > nul )
```

The `/t` value is in **seconds**

This prevent the timeout command to write "Waiting for n seconds ..." so it's kind of silent.

If you want to go faster than 1 second you can do the following:

```
for /l %g in () do @( <your-command> & ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500 > nul )
```

Answer (score 0):

[PowerShell-Watch](http://wragg.io/watch-for-changes-with-powershell)

[Code Repository](https://github.com/markwragg/PowerShell-Watch)

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements on the excellent PS module written by johnrizzo1 (see [here](https://superuser.com/a/768081/1235719))

- Renamed function to be in line with Powershell naming convention (as suggested by duct_tape_coder)
- Moved interval to second argument, so it's optional; reduced default to 2 seconds
- Fetch output of Invoke first, only then refresh the screen. This avoids the screen going blank while the command executes

```
function Watch-Command {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True,ConfirmImpact='High')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$command,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [int]$interval = 2
    )
    process {
        $cmd = [scriptblock]::Create($command);
        While($True) {
            $output = $cmd.Invoke();
            cls;
            Write-Host "Command: " $command;
            Write-Host ($output | Out-String);
            sleep $interval;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(1) { clear; Command ;sleep 3; }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

I was in a hurry.... I used one suggestion and changed it a little to work for me:

```
for /l %g in () do @( echo test & timeout /t 2 )
```

I changed it to:

```
for /l %g in () do @( test.bat & timeout /t 2 )
```

And I created the `test.bat` file with the command line.  In my case, it was:

```
net group <NAME> /domain
```

I found that the `echo` command just printed out to the screen but did not execute the command

Comment: "_the echo command just printed out to the screen_" - that's exactly what the `echo` command does