# How to monitor the realtime content of a folder in commandline

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

Is there any way to monitor the real time content of a folder in commandline? What i need is like *dir* command but updates the content continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer from a different question on this site (with the help of @RoseHosting). The [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/191063/what-is-the-windows-analog-of-the-linux-watch-command/191068#191068) belongs to the @harrymc.

I have written something like that;

```
@ECHO OFF
:loop
  %*
 dir "path/to/myFolder"
  timeout /t 5
goto loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You may find the following command helpful:

```
watch -n1 ls /path/to/directory
```

It will list the content of the '/path/to/directory' directory and update the report every one second. You can modify the -n option according to your needs.

Comment: It is exactly what I am looking but when i enter the command, it says the command "watch" is not found or written false.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just noticed that you have Windows OS. I'm not sure, but I don't think that the 'watch' command is available for Windows. You will have to find an alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much. With the help of your answer, I could find a similar soluation on Windows :)