# How can I replicate the `watch` command on Windows to monitor GPU usage?

Tags: linux, windows, gpu

I usually work with a Linux server to train deep learning models. When I use my work server, I simply do `watch -n 5 nvidia-smi` and I get the output for `nvidia-smi` at five second intervals.

I'd like to replicate this behavior for my personal desktop as well, but am not sure how. I've taken a look at this question: [What is the Windows analog of the Linux watch command?](https://superuser.com/questions/191063/what-is-the-windows-analog-of-the-linux-watch-command) but the answers seem rather..."hacky."

Is there any other standard way that I can monitor GPU usage without having to install any third party tool? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the help page: `nvidia-smi -h`.

You can find the commands `nvidia-smi -l` and `nvidia-smi -lms` there. The former loops every given seconds and the latter every given milliseconds.

So in your case the equivalent would be `nvidia-smi -l 5`

Comment: Also for future readers, you can use `while (1) {nvidia-smi; sleep 1; clear}` to flush the previous outputs.